# Conditional statement to check if you are in a git repository in shell

Tags: bash, git

I'm trying to edit my git bash terminal on Windows in the `C:/Program Files/Git/etc/profile.d/git-prompt.sh` directory and I want to check if my current working directory is a Git repository.

Below is my current code:

```bash
if test -f /etc/profile.d/git-sdk.sh
then
    TITLEPREFIX=SDK-${MSYSTEM#MINGW}
else
    TITLEPREFIX=$MSYSTEM
fi

if test -f ~/.config/git/git-prompt.sh
then
    . ~/.config/git/git-prompt.sh
else
    PS1='\[\033]0;$TITLEPREFIX:$PWD\007\]' # set window title
    PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[1;32m\]'       # change to green
    PS1="$PS1"'➜  '                 # arrow
    PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[1;36m\]'      # change color to bold cyan
    PS1="$PS1"'\W'                  # current working directory
    if test -z "$WINELOADERNOEXEC"
    then
        GIT_EXEC_PATH="$(git --exec-path 2>/dev/null)"
        COMPLETION_PATH="${GIT_EXEC_PATH%/libexec/git-core}"
        COMPLETION_PATH="${COMPLETION_PATH%/lib/git-core}"
        COMPLETION_PATH="$COMPLETION_PATH/share/git/completion"
        # if test -z "$COMPLETION_PATH/git-prompt.sh"
        # then
        . "$COMPLETION_PATH/git-completion.bash"
        . "$COMPLETION_PATH/git-prompt.sh"
        # if test -n `git branch --show-current` 
        # then
        PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[1;34m\]'                  # change color to cyan
        PS1="$PS1"' git:('                          # bash function
        PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[1;31m\]'                  # change color to cyan
        PS1="$PS1"'`git branch --show-current`'     # get current working branch
        PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[1;34m\]'                  # change color to bold blue
        PS1="$PS1"') '                              # close brackets

        PS1="$PS1"'\n'                  # new line
        PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[1;33m\]'      # change color to bold yellow
        PS1="$PS1"'$ '                  # prompt: always $
        PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[0m\]'         # change color to default
        # fi
        # fi
    fi
fi

MSYS2_PS1="$PS1"                    # for detection by MSYS2 SDK's bash.basrc

# Evaluate all user-specific Bash completion scripts (if any)
if test -z "$WINELOADERNOEXEC"
then
    for c in "$HOME"/bash_completion.d/*.bash
    do
        # Handle absence of any scripts (or the folder) gracefully
        test ! -f "$c" ||
        . "$c"
    done
fi
```

I'm trying to create a conditional statement to test if my current directory is a Git repository and if so, display the correct format.

If I open my terminal in a Git repository:

```
➜  test-repo git:(main)
$
```

If I open my terminal **without** Git repository:

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
➜  test-repo git:() 
$
```

The intension is to remove `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git` and `git:()` if I'm not in a Git repository.

Comment: Just an idea: You could do a `git status` and catch the error message (if any). I guess that git will report an error if you are not in a repo.

Comment: `if git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree &> /dev/null; then ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
if git status -s 1>&2 2>/dev/null
then
  : You are in a git repo
else
  : You are not
fi
```

**UPDATE** : A faster alternative to `git status -s` would be

```
git rev-parse -q --short HEAD
```